# parametric overlay in context

Tags: context, overlays, metapost

I am trying to make something like excel databars in context TABLE enviroment. I have created overlay, that should draw the databar, but I can't figure out, how to pass data into that overlay.

Is it possible to make something like

```
\defineoverlay[demo circle #1][\useMPgraphic{demo circle}{color=#1}]
```

??? or is there any other way, how to draw cell background of TBALE (\bTD) by Metapost and pass in data, that will be accessible by \MPvar?

minimal working example:

```
\mainlanguage[cz]
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuplayout[topspace=2cm,backspace=2cm,width=middle,height=middle,header=0.6cm,footer=0.7cm,footerdistance=0.2cm,headerdistance=0.2cm]
\setupcolors[state=start]

\startuseMPgraphic{demo circle}
path p ;
p := fullcircle xscaled \overlaywidth yscaled \overlayheight ;
fill p withcolor .85white ;
draw p withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor \MPvar{color} ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[demo circle #1][\useMPgraphic{demo circle}{color=#1}]

\starttext

\placetable{Test}{\bTABLE
\bTR \bTD[background=demo circle blue] aaaaa \eTD \bTD[background=demo circle red] bbbbb \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD[background=demo circle green] cccccc \eTD \bTD[background=demo circle black] dddddd \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @cfr: I agree with the spirit of your comment (the need for a MWE), but note that this is a question related to ConTeXt, so there will be no `\documentclass{...}` ... `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Aditya Oops. Indeed. I cut-and-pasted the standard comment block without thinking about it, but you are obviously right.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to pass color options to a frame is to use the `framecolor` key. The value of that key can be accessed using  `\overlaylinecolor`. For example:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\startuseMPgraphic{demo circle}
   newpath p ;
   p := fullcircle xscaled \overlaywidth yscaled \overlayheight ;
   fill p withcolor .85white ;
   draw p withpen pencircle scaled 2pt withcolor \MPcolor{\overlaylinecolor} ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[demo circle][\useMPgraphic{demo circle}]

\starttext

\placetable{Test}
  {\bTABLE
      \bTR 
          \bTD[background=demo circle, framecolor=red]
              aaaaa
          \eTD
          \bTD[background=demo circle, framecolor=red]
              bbbbb 
          \eTD 
      \eTR
      \bTR 
          \bTD[background=demo circle, framecolor=green]
              cccccc
          \eTD 
          \bTD[background=demo circle, framecolor=green]
              dddddd 
          \eTD 
      \eTR
  \eTABLE}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

You can use `frame=off` to avoid the default frames.